# Задача с гаммированием. С++

Tags: c++

Вот мой код шифрования. Я считываю из файла по 8 символов и складываю их, а когда в конце остается менее 8 символов программа сама их дописывает. Подскажите как избежать этого.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
  int  x, q=0;
  char ch;
  char mas1[8];
  char *mas2;
  char mas3[8];

  char gam[8] = {'Ï', 'k', 'O', 'Q', 'á', 'ÿ', 'Y', 'v'};
  ifstream infile("File.txt");
  ofstream outfile("Ofile.txt");
  while(infile)
   {
    ++q;
    mas2 = new char[x];
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
     {
      infile.get(ch);
      if(!infile.eof())
       {
        mas2[i]=ch;
       }
      else
       i = 8;
     }
    if(q==1)
     {
      for(int j=0; j<8; ++j)
       {
        mas3[j] = mas2[j] ^ gam[j];
        outfile.put(mas3[j]);
       }
     } else
     {
      for(int c=0; c<8; ++c)
       {
        if(mas2[c])
         {
          mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];
          outfile.put(mas3[c]);
         }
        else
         c=8;
       }
     }
    for(int w=0; w<8; ++w)
     {
      mas1[w] = mas3[w];
     }
    delete[] mas2;
   }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Гаммировать надо поток битов с хотя бы последовательностью следов в конечном поле.

Comment: У вас у переменной `x` не задано значение, интересно какого размера массивы выделяются и как оно вообще работает после такого. И гамма обычно псевдослучайная последовательность не повторяющаяся на всей длине шифротекста.

Comment: Для выхода из цикла есть ключевое слово `break`, ставить счетчик цикла на максимум для прерывания не надо. А еще не понятно зачем на каждой итерации выделять и освобождать память под mas2

Comment: А как сделать так что бы здесь for(int c=0; c<; ++c)
    {
     if(mas2[c])
     {
     mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];
     outfile.put(mas3[c]);

     }
не складывались лишние символы? как поставить условие?

Comment: Давайте все по порядку. Я пока еще не вник в алгоритм, но подозреваю, что проблема i=8 вместо break - это корень всех бед, потому как последующие циклы должны работать не до 8, а до `i` т.е. до кол-ва байт которые реально считаны.

Comment: Суть в том что я беру из файла по 8 символов. Первые 8 символов я просто с гаммой складываю, а получившийся шифр текст я уже складываю с гаммой и следующими 8-ю символами из файла. И когда в конце файла остаётся (к примеру) 5 символов, программа сама дописывает оставшиеся 3 символа. я хочу узнать, как поставить условие выхода из 3-го цикла for чтобы избежать этих лишних символов

Answer (score 1):

Модифицируйте вашу программу так:

1. Надо сохранить `i` для последующего использования, цикл чтения выглядит так:

   ```
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
    {
     infile.get(ch);
     if(!infile.eof())
      {
       mas2[i]=ch;
      }
     else
      break; // Выходим из цикла, i остается равной кол-ву реально считанных символов
    }
   ```
2. Циклы записи должны оканчиваться на кол-ве реально считанных байт

   ```
   for(int c=0; c<i; ++c) ...
   ```

Аналогично для второго цикла записи

Помимо этого предлагаю задать значение переменной `k`, а `new` и `delete` для массива mas2 вынести за пределы основного `while`, нет смысла выделять и освобождать память на каждом проходе.

Для быстрого копирования массива в другой, вместо цикла `w` можно использовать функцию `memcpy(mas1,mas3,8)`

И серьезное замечание к самому алгоритму: Даже если вы потом сделаете возможность менять ключ шифрования это ровным счетом ничего не изменит, потому как криптоаналитик просто возьмет первые 8 байт вашего широтекста (зашифрованого сообщения) и выполнит `xor` этих байт с следующими 8 байтами - при этом он получит расшифрованные вторые 8 байт. Далее он наложит полученные байты на 3й блок и получит для этого блока сообщение^ключ, наложит на 4й блок и получит его в открытом виде. Таким образом даже не зная ключа можно сходу расшифровать все четные 8ми байтные блоки. Вычислить после этого ключ и расшифровать остальные так же не составит труда. В общем дополнительное усложнение алгоритма, которое вы сделали, сохраняя предыдущий блок и используя его при шифровании следующего не увеличило, а значительно снизило криптостойкость алгоритма

```
1й блок:  x ^ k = o
2й блок:  y ^ x ^ k = m
взлом  :  o ^ m = (x ^ k) ^ (y ^ x ^ k) = (x ^ x) ^ (k ^ k) ^ y = y
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как передать значение i  в следующие циклы?

Comment: Ой, я забыл поправить второе предложение :) Сейчас поправил. В общем переменную `i` надо объявить чуть раньше чем начинается цикл (можно вообще в начало программы это вынести) и циклы записи сделать вида `for(int c=0; c<i; ++c)`

Comment: @ВладимирСамофал И еще раз обращаю внимание, что это сложно назвать гаммированием. Я на спор такие шифры вскрывал на достаточном объеме _текста_ при примерно 500 байтном ключе, заранее неизвестной длины. На двоичных данных, конечно я бы не взялся, но я далеко не криптоаналитик. Настоящее гаммирование делается `xor` с псевдослучаной гаммой длиной с шифротекст, получаемой хотя бы алгоритмом RANDU (в гугле вбейте, почитайте) (хотя криптоаналитики randu давно забраковали :) )

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я приму ваши советы к сведению.

Comment: @ВладимирСамофал Так сложно сказать, проверьте имена файлов. Регистр букв (если вы под *nix)

Comment: программа почему то не хочет читать файл с шифр текстом

Comment: @ВладимирСамофал Смотрю и не вижу. С виду все так же как и  у              той. А может она раньше завершается потому что выходной файл уже существует. Попробуйте для out файла другое имя здать. хотя я не знаю как эти стримы работают

Answer (score 1):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int x, q=0;
char ch;
char mas1[8];
char mas2[8];
char mas3[8];
char gam[8] = {'П', 'k', 'O', 'Q', 'б', 'я', 'Y', 'v'};
ifstream infile("Ofile.txt");
ofstream outfile("File.txt");
while(infile)
{
++q;
int i;
for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
 infile.get(ch);
 if(!infile.eof())
  {
 mas2[i]=ch;

 }
 else
 break;
 }
if(q==1)
{
 for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
  {
   mas3[j] = mas2[j] ^ gam[j];
   outfile.put(mas3[j]);

   }
   }
   else
   {
    for(int c=0; c<i; ++c)
    {

     mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];
     outfile.put(mas3[c]);

     }

   }
  for(int w=0; w<i; ++w)
   {
    mas1[w] = mas2[w];

    }

   }

        return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```